# consulta sql con varios resultados

Tags: php, sql, array, mysqli

Tengo una consulta sql

`SELECT titulo FROM eventos WHERE organizador="pepito"`

y me arroja este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en php:

```
$evento = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT titulo FROM eventos WHERE organizador='$organizador'");
$eve= mysqli_fetch_array($evento);
for($cont2=0;$cont2<count($eve);$cont2++){
    $eventos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT titulo, fecha, hora, FROM eventos WHERE titulo='$eve[$cont2]'");
```

Pero no me resulta, sale el resultado del primer array, en este caso `$eve[0]` pero como vemos arriba en la imagen son 4 resultados. No se si estoy haciendo algo mal, estoy iniciandome esto.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué no traes todos los datos que necesitas de una vez en la primera consulta?

Comment: por cada titulo que encuentre en la primera consulta, me genera un div con los datos de la segunda consulta. Es decir, la primera consulta trae Prueba1, y con ese dato hago la segunda consulta para llenar la informacion del div (titulo, fecha, hora).

La idea es que el segundo div sea el de Prueba 45 con los datos de ese titulo Y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Puedes traer todos los datos en la primera consulta de una vez, y utilizarlos en el ciclo para ir creando los divs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las dos consultas indican que los datos están **en la misma tabla**:

1ª consulta: `SELECT titulo FROM eventos WHERE organizador='$organizador'`

2ª consulta: `SELECT titulo, fecha, hora, FROM eventos WHERE titulo='$eve[$cont2]'`

Entonces, no tiene ningún sentido consultar una y otra vez la misma tabla. Trae todos los datos en una sola consulta y luego ve creando los `divs`.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Incluye en el SELECT todas las columnas que necesitas
$eventos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT titulo, fecha, hora FROM eventos WHERE organizador='$organizador'");
#Variable para ir concatenando los divs
$html="";
#mysqli_fetch_assoc es más específico para el tipo de lectura que necesitas aquí
while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($eventos) ) {
    $html.="
             <div>
                  <h1>$row[titulo]</h1>
                      <p>Fecha: $row[fecha]</p>
                      <p>Hora: $row[hora]</p>
             </div>
            ";
}
#Imprimimos $html, que debería tener un div por cada fila
echo $html;
```

Comment: gracias amigo funciono a la perfeccion... soy nuevo y ahora me doy cuenta las vueltas q estaba haciendo... me la simplificaste...gracias